# Binding a Filtered ObservableCollection to a ListView while keeping Two-Way binding?

Tags: c#, listview, filter, windows-store-apps

Is it possible for an **ObservableCollection** binded to a **ListView** to return **ONLY a filtered sub-set of Items** while keeping the **TWO-WAY binding**? So when I add / remove items, the changes will reflect to the UI?

Basically, I have a **AllItems** ObservableCollection and have **FilteredItems** ObservableCollection that is binded on the 2nd ListView level. When adding / removing items, **AllItems** is the one changed, but **FilteredItems** references that and gets subset of items based on a certain filter.

I have 2 nested ListViews. It looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Seats}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSeat, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_CheckItems" IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckItemsSeatsDisplayCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCheckItem,
                                         Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  Grid.Column="1">
            </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" ></WrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

My Main ViewModel looks something like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
private ObservableCollection<SeatsViewModel> _Seats = null;
public ObservableCollection<SeatsViewModel> Seats
{
    get
    {
        return _Seats;
    }
    set
    {
        _Seats = value;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<CheckItemsViewModel> _AllCheckItems = null;
public ObservableCollection<CheckItemsViewModel> AllCheckItems
{
    get
    {
        return _AllCheckItems;
    }
    set
    {
        _AllCheckItems = value;
    }
}
}
```

And my SeatsViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SeatsViewModel
{
public int SeatNumber {get;set;}

public ObservableCollection<CheckItemsViewModel> _CheckItemsSeatsDisplayCollection
{
    get
    {
        //I want to return only a subset of the items in AllCheckItems
        //return ParentViewModel.Instance.AllCheckItems.Where(c => c.SeatNumber.Equals(SeatNumber));
    }
}
}
```

I can't do a LINQ query and return that because it returns IEnumerable and that doesn't track changes when binded.

Am I doing something wrong / is there another way of doing what I want to achieve?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CollectionViewSource to do what you want. It's a way to filter. Have a look at the [MSDN article on CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

If you need more flexibility you can also use the solution that was provided on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So).

UPDATE

You could also register for the CollectionChanged event, and in the handler add or delete it to the original Collection. Changing items should be handled separately this way. 
In these cases I normally have a property that returns the result of a Linq query as an IEnumerable. Changes are then always done in the original object. Of course you need to do the Collection-changes yourself then. But if that is done with a button, it's easy as well. I then have a CollectionChanged handler on the original collection to trigger OnPropertyChanged for the filtered properties.

Hope this helps. Binding cannot solve ALL scenario's :)

Martin

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried that path before and unfortunately, the binding disappears (ex. if I add an item to the collection, it was not reflected on the UI. I had to bind it again).

What I ended up doing was attaching a behavior to each ListViewItem and changing the Visibility dynamically to Visible or Collapsed depending on their parents in the Visual Tree.